# Are there more bending units named Bender?

Tags: futurama, bender-rodriguez

Bender is a [bending unit](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Bending_Unit).

Bender was given the name Bender, same as Flexo was given his name.

Under the assumption that bending units are given names having to do with **bending**, are there other bending units ***also*** called Bender?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have not been any other [bending units](http://theinfosphere.org/Bending_Units) with the name "Bender" appearing in the series (not counting [parallel Benders](http://theinfosphere.org/Parallel_Universe) or [time paradox duplicates](http://theinfosphere.org/Time_paradox_duplicate)). However, there have been two other named robots with the same *appearance* as Bender: [Flexo](http://theinfosphere.org/Flexo) and [Billy West](http://theinfosphere.org/Billy_West_%28robot%29).

Also, Bender was just a *particular* model of bending unit: model #22. There have been other models of bending units, both male and female (such as [Angleyne](http://theinfosphere.org/Angleyne)). Here are some other models from the bending competitions of the Robot Olympics:

[image: Manbots]

[image: Fembots]