# How do futurama robots acquire names?

Tags: futurama, robots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there more bending units called Bender?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18228/are-there-more-bending-units-called-bender)

[Bender](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender_Bending_Rodriguez) is a [bending robot](http://theinfosphere.org/Bending_Unit). The other Bending Robots (model #22) [Flexo](http://theinfosphere.org/Flexo) and [Billy West](http://theinfosphere.org/Billy_West_%28robot%29) have different names.

What makes Bender the odd one out here? Why doesn't he have a different *first* name? Or are Flexo and Billy the odd ones out and all other have the Bender prefix?

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18228/are-there-more-bending-units-called-bender

Comment: Why do you claim Bender is the odd one out?  If any of the three is, Billy West is the odd one out because it has nothing to do with bending.

Comment: Because Bender is called Bender Bending Rodriguez, Flexo is just Flexo. They are both the same unit, a Bending model. Bender is the only one with the unit name in his name.

Comment: @Dason not even related. it seems like a duplicate...

Comment: @TheDoctor I thought they were highly related but I don't necessarily see this question as an exact duplicate